# magento manage page not displayed in admin

Tags: php, magento

Magento manage page in the admin area will not display. Everything works perfectly in the admin area, except for the static block page and the manage pages, which do not display.

Comment: Someone should add a feature to PHP that logs errors to a text file. They could call it error_log. That would make debugging these questions super easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some basic debugging to get anywhere with this question. Enable the error log and check it for errors on the page, this will hopefully give you an error message if you don't have one already. Edit your question to include that error message.

If you have any new modules, remove them temporarily. If you have version control (you have it, right?), try reverting to an older version of the code that works, and then see what changed between the two versions. Report your results back here.

Thanks,
Joe